# Linux + how to shutdown application properly with reboot or init 0 + init.d scripts

Tags: linux, bash, init-script, init.d

I have Linux Redhat (version 6.5) machine that manages some application
before each reboot or `init 0`

I shutdown the application as the follows:

```
/etc/app-LM.bash
/etc/app-UPP.pl 
/bin/DT-apl.c
```

1. What is the procedure if I want these steps to run automatically with reboot or `init 0` ?
2. How can I tell if the following service will activate during
   reboot?

```
# chkconfig --list |grep super
superAPP_ng       0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:off   5:on    6:off
```

Comment: You should tell people the *version* of your operating system.  It is important.

Comment: I marked the OS version and add additional question ( second )